# How to add console build to a C# windows service app and have the console show up?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I've got a project that was originally built as a C# Windows Service in Visual Studio 2019. I've made changes to conditionally compile it both as a service and as a console app. The problem I'm having is that when the app is run in console mode, it runs as a background process and never shows the console. Is there some setting that will have this run as a normal console app?

I know the app is indeed running because when I debug it, it will stop at my break points after it receives a data packet.

Comment: Have you got some code?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this: (no need to conditionally compile)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            Service s = new Service();
            s.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceClass());
        }
    }
```